# Having trouble with a memory leak - rebinding keys in std::map

Tags: c++, dictionary

```
void filename_changed(string originalfilename, string newfilename) {
    auto it = file_source_map.find(originalfilename);
    if (it == file_source_map.end())
        return;
    file_source_map.insert(std::pair<const string, string>(newfilename, it->second));
    file_source_map.erase(originalfilename);
}
```

I replaced the allocators of std::map and std::string, so I know for certain that this is leaking memory, but I can't see the issue. If originalfilename exists in the map, insert it's value at newfilename, and erase originalfilename.

Comment: Where is `it` getting declared? Or are you just missing its type in the first line of the function?

Comment: @Nick: C++0x auto - automatic type deduction. But I'm going to delete this question anyway, because I made some progress on my own and need to ask a totally different question.

Comment: Ah ok, haven't looked into C++0x much! Sorry for the confusion :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except for the simpler (probably replaced while investigating the memory leak)

```
file_source_map.insert(std::make_pair(newfilename, it->second));
file_source_map.erase(it);
```

and a check that both filenames are not the same (which would not leak, but actually erase the entry), there is nothing obvious wrong with the code.

Check other things (like the allocators?).

Comment: Yes, I've just determined that the allocator is at fault.

Comment: It turns out that I took the allocated size as a count of T, and the deallocated size as a raw byte size, so the deallocated size always appeared to be much less than the allocated size.

Answer (score 0):

Since keys are unique in std::map, Shouldn't you erase the old key, value and then insert the new key,value?